# Batch remove former of two file extensions

Tags: bash, macos, file-extension

I am working with many pictures on a MacOSX 10.12. 
In order to do some image analyses I need to change the format from .JPG to .gif.

Using ImageMagick I did it relatively quickly, and now I have multiple files with the double extension *.JPG.gif.

I would like to remove the ".JPG" part from the file name but for some reason what I am doing is not working. (I should say that this step is probably not critical to what I have to do next, but since I have a lot of files simplifying their name as much as possible is probably best. I should also say that I have all the super user permission and none of the file names actually contain brakes or spaces so even adding the "" to my code doesn't change anything).

Here is what I am trying using a bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in /folder/*.JPG.gif
          do
            mv $file ${file#.JPG}
          done
```

My understanding is that this code should remove the .JPG part from $file starting the match from the front of the file's name. And yet when I call the ls command to see if the program did what it is supposed to do, all the names are still there with the double extension.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `mv` command like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /folder/*.JPG.gif
      do
        mv "$file" "${file/\.JPG}"
      done
```

Your initial code uses an expansion that removes text from the beginning, not in the middle.  The expansion above removes inside the string.

Please note that this is not very robust.  If you have ".JPG" in your path or filenames anywhere except at the end of your filenames, it will not do what you want.  Quoting, even if not necessary in your case for now, is still good practice as things change, and code gets copy and pasted.

Comment: By the way, I like this source as a summary of various forms of expansion in bash: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.